# My Identity server 4 applicatioin cannot connect to internet

Tags: docker, networking, microservices, identityserver4, docker-network

I'm triyng to build an Identity Server 4 application. Outside containers is running very well. When I put it in the container IdentityServer4 doesn't want to communicate with internet. I can reach the application on Localhost:5001, but can't login with "Google" for example. It says "Error loading external login information". This is my docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  firstidsrvaspnetidentity:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "5001:443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
  db:
    volumes:
      - type: volume
#        source: firstidsrvaspnetidentitydb
#        target: /var/opt/mssql/data
        source: firstidsrvaspnetidentitydbsys
        target: /var/opt/mssql
      - type: volume
        source: firstidsrvaspnetidentitydbusr
        target: /var/opt/sqlserver   

  mvcclient:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "5002:443"
    volumes:
       - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
       - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
volumes:
  firstidsrvaspnetidentitydbsys:
  firstidsrvaspnetidentitydbusr:
```

Also when I try to reach IdentityServer from my MVC application it gives me this

"SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"

This is from docker inspect the network connection:

```
    {
    "Name": "dockercompose13710950502249966985_default",
    "Id": "6bfb2a7384731a4ed3ea8de9a4c314762b94b200e8c2cf90642394957b2e6f26",
    "Created": "2020-09-27T01:46:10.278679Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {
        "36afbe4e8c621990e03a418598dc08700f45b1052b23884d6b2030d0244ef0a7": {
            "Name": "FirstIdSrvAspNetIdentity",
            "EndpointID": "38389acc8d76ce323ccaa9cae56848f73602b41b7b34ebab4385cbc7165f4803",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:04",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.4/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "3eb81a2a503b43a0d40c1796b3cb4254ef133cd3438518595f7ab6476448eb52": {
            "Name": "dockercompose13710950502249966985_db_1",
            "EndpointID": "a6d6b787e8734ae97998deed7636eb48bc4829da54a09bb5d4aa7c754052d12a",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        },
        "bb90474e61ddc1808679ebd0ce86ede54e8f3cd2780e027595cf21032382b3d0": {
            "Name": "MVCClient",
            "EndpointID": "73bfcf060bb4c944d23aabd21d2318ca133735cdf765f934031abcf3d6f868b2",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:03",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.3/16",
            "IPv6Address": ""
        }
    },
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {
        "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
        "com.docker.compose.project": "dockercompose13710950502249966985",
        "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.2"
    }
```

Any helps or ideas will be much appreceted. Thank you.